# Asking User to play again

Tags: python

I don't know how to include a play again "loop" with the current code I have. I put a boolAgain = "" so it null's it out but I don't know where to go from there and how I'm going to get there or if I'm doing this correctly.

```
#This imports the random generator
import random

#Sets up variables
strName = ""
strError1 = "ERROR! Please put in correct input."
CONLOW = 1
intTotalScore = 0
intGamesPlayed = 0
intCount = 0
intHigh = 0
intScore = 0
intRandom = 0
intGuess = 0
intGuesses = 0
boolAgain = "yes"

#This is an input asking the users name with an added error catch
while strName.isspace() or len(strName) <=1\
      or strName.isdigit() or (any(char.isdigit() for char in strName)): 
    strName = str(input("What is your name? "))

#This is to keep the game on
while boolAgain == "yes":
    #This is for inputting a level
    while True:
        intLevel = int(input("You are here to guess the random number, \n"
                         "What level do you want to play?\n"
                         "1 and 10 or 1 and 100.\n"
                         "Please answer\n\n"
                         "'1' for 1 to 10\n"
                         "'2' for 1 to 100\n"
                         "'3' for 1 to 1000\n"
                         "\n"
                         "What is your choice? "))
        if intLevel == 1:
            intHigh = 10
            intScore = 10
            intTotalScore += intScore
            intRandom = random.randint (CONLOW, intHigh)
            intGamesPlayed += 1
            print(intRandom)
            break
        elif intLevel == 2:
            intHigh = 100
            intScore = 20
            intTotalScore += intScore
            intRandom = random.randint (CONLOW, intHigh)
            intGamesPlayed += 1
            print(intRandom)
            break
        elif intLevel == 3:
            intHigh = 1000
            intScore = 30
            intTotalScore += intScore
            intRandom = random.randint (CONLOW, intHigh)
            intGamesPlayed += 1
            print(intRandom)
            break
        else:
            print(strError1)
            continue
    #used to generate the random number        


    while intGuess != intRandom:
        intGuess = int(input("Guess the number "))
        if intGuess < intRandom:
            print('Your guess is too low.') 
        elif intGuess > intRandom:
            print('Your guess is too high.')
        elif intGuess == intRandom:
            print("\n", strName, "you are right")
            print("    ", str(intGamesPlayed), "is how much you've played \n")
            print("    ", str(intScore), "is your score for this round \n")
            print("    ", str(intTotalScore), "is your total for all rounds \n")
            boolAgain = ""
        else:
            print(strError)
```

My initial code for this was going to be:

```
> while boolAgain != "no" or boolAgain != "yes":
>     boolAgain = input("Do you want to play again? 'yes' or 'no' ")
> if boolAgain == "no":
>     print("Goodbye " + strName)
> elif boolAgain == "yes":
>     True #I really do not know what im doing here
> else:
>     print(strError1)
```

I swear this is all wrong. Please help :--)

UPDATE

I have repeatedly gotten the same negative results. I think the solution will possibly be making the indents better, I am not eally sure. Whenever I type in "yes", it says "You are playing again, " + strName but then it stops and it doesn't repeat the code again.

Comment: Put your game code inside of a function and call that function any time you want to play again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want a big outer `while` loop for playing the game again, in which you have another `while` loop to check for `yes` or `no`, and the actual game. So:

```
boolAgain = True
while boolAgain:
  #here is where the actual game goes
  #yay game
  #end of game

  #asking the user if he/she wants to continue:
  noAnswer = True
  while noAnswer:
    answer = input("Do you want to play again? 'yes' or 'no' ")
    if answer == 'yes':
      noAnswer = False
      print("You are playing again, " + strName)
      #boolAgain doesn't change and is still True
    if answer == 'no':
      noAnswer = False
      boolAgain = False
      print("Goodbye " + strName)
    else:
      print("you must answer 'yes' or 'no'")
```

Note that a boolean is `True` or `False`, and `'yes'` and `'no'` is just a bit of text. So `True` can be used easily in an if-statement. For 'yes' you'll need to compare it to the actual string value `'yes'`.

**UPDATE:**
Also, as R Nar said, put the game into a function as such:

```
def play_game():
  something = 1
  something_else = input("give a number higher than 1")
  if int(something_else) > something: #the number given is still text and not an integer
    result = 'win'
  else:
    result = 'lose'
  print('you ' + result + '!')

boolAgain = True
while boolAgain:
  play_game()

  #asking the user if he/she wants to continue (see code earlier in answer)
```

**New update:**

In your code, after asking for a name you start with `while boolAgain == 'yes':`. At this point in the code, boolAgain does not yet exist. Also, set the boolean boolAgain to the native python value of `True` (it's a single bit), rather than the text value of `'yes'`. So the line should look like this:

```
boolAgain = True
while boolAgain == True:
```

or with a slight abbreviation (technical: as `boolAgain == True` gives `True`, the same value as `boolAgain` already is):

```
boolAgain = True
while boolAgain:
```

Next, in your game, you change `boolAgain` right after `print("    ", int(intTotalScore), "is your total for all rounds \n")`, don't do that.

Also, you ask your user if they want to play again when already out of the playing-the-game-while-loop. You should ask this within the while loop, and answering 'no' should take you out of the playing-the-game-while-loop. This is because there is no indent.

In the asking a user if they want to play again, you can copy the `while noAnswer:` part earlier in this post and work from there

Comment: My class is not advanced enough to do functions so I am not comfortable with it yet but I did try your suggestion and it sadly did not work for me. I tried doing something very different yet the boolAgain is still not working.

Comment: @sp00kys0up Your boolAgain should be set to `True` at the start (before the loop), and only to `False` if the user answers `'no'`, you could try using `print(boolAgain)` in various places to see where it changes when it shouldn't, or doesn't change when it should.

Comment: I changed it back to what it originally was and I just included the print(boolAgain). It's True throughout, yet it gives me the strError and asks  if I want to play again.

Comment: Just figured out the problem. It was quite due to my slight carelessness.